# Form parameters not getting sent?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am trying to make a login request but for some reason none of the inputs are getting sent with the request.

Have a bad feeling it's just some stupid mistake but I have been looking for 2h now and I can't find anything.

CODE:

Html / Laravel Blade:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="validate" required>
            <label for="username" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Username</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate" required>
            <label for="password" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Password</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <button class="btn btn-block waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::post( '/admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login' )->name( 'admin.login' );
```

Controller:

```
public function login( Request $request )
{
    dd($request);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: try dd($request->all()); and show me what u get

Comment: Error: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()"

Comment: change namespace to:  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `dd($request->all());`

And make sure you are using the right namespace for Http requests:

```
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Not:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```